# Is there a way to input a function from black cmd screen (stdin)?

Tags: c

I was asked to write a program using Riemann sum to calculate integrals numerically. I ENDED that code (thank God), but I want to take it further: Adding functions from the black cmd screen.

But I can't seem to find any way to do it. I skimmed through tonnes of books but can't seem to find anything about it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
double mulfun (double x) {
    /*I want to add function from the black screen here*/
    double q = (x*x+5*x+1); //but you can change q to any functions you want
    double s = exp(x)*q; //this is basically homework :)
    return s;
}
double polynomial(double x) {
    int u;
    printf("Insert degree of this polynomial?\t");
    scanf("%d", &u);
    u = u + 1;
    float z[u];
    int k;
    for (k = u - 1; k <= 0; k-- ) {
        printf("\nInsert term of x^%d\t",z[k]);
        scanf("%f%*c", &z[k]);
    }
    double s = z[0];
    for (k=1; k<(u); k++) {
        s = s + z[k]*pow(x,k);
    }
    return s;
}
double riemann (double (*f) (double), double a, double b, double n) {
    double delta, s = 0;
    int i;
    delta = (b - a)/(double)n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s = s + delta*(f(a + i*delta + delta/2));
    };
    return s;
}
/*mulfun is the function where you add your functions in*/
void main() {
/* a is the lower-bound, b is the upper-bound, n is number of parts
inteval [a, b] is divided into*/
    float a, b, n;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    scanf("%f", &b);
    scanf("%f", &n);
    double e = riemann (mulfun, a, b, n);
    printf("%f", e);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You would need to write a function that accepts input in a very specific format and then write a general function that takes the processed input (like an array of coefficients for example) and evaluate it using input parameters.

Comment: You have two options: either have a list of predefined (hardcoded) functions and let the user input only specific strings that map directly to the built-in functions (say, inputting `"cos"` will call the built-in `cos` function) or build your own tiny (?) programming language that would allow to define functions.

Comment: @ForceBru I think the second option is wayyyy too hard for me :) first one it is :)

Comment: @ForceBru or embed an existing one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, yeah, something like Lua. It may be possible to parse the input to an AST and then make `riemann` work with that AST and simulate calls to this function. Or even simpler: deduce the function's signature and make `riemann` execute Lua code that calls the function with parameters provided by `riemann`...

Comment: Woah I need to do even more research then :)))))

Comment: What do you mean by "Adding functions from the black cmd screen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is known in some languages as an `eval()` function, or `evaluation` more generally.  e.g., in Perl, you can call `eval(STRING)`, where `STRING` is an arbitrary string -- for example, that the user supplied as input, just like you are wanting to do -- and `STRING` would be interpreted as Perl code and executed as such.

That's a summary.  There are many finer details to consider, like scope, exit status, exception handling, security, etc.  It's tricky enough even when the language supplies an `eval()` function; it's full of pitfalls and sharp edges trying to implement one yourself.

But, C does not have an equivalent to `eval()`.  My main point in posting this answer is to give you a commonly-used term for conducting further research.  Knowing that you are talking about a class of programming tasks that goes by the general term `eval` or `evaluation` can help focus your research.

e.g., here is one place to start : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!